# Laravel 5.4 - Cache an array

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am trying to cache an array, but for some reason, nothing is added. This is the code:

```
public static function getEmployees()
    {

        if(!Cache::has('employees')):

            $data      = ['urlPath' => '/employees/directory'];

            $params    = ['fields' => 'jobTitle'];

            $employees = API::callAPI('GET', $data, $params);

            Cache::putMany($employees, 1440);

        endif;

        return Cache::get('employees');

    }
```

And whey I try to get cached value (array), I am getting null:

```
dd(Cache::get('employees'));
```

And this is an array I want to store:

```
array:2 [▼
  "fields" => array:16 [▶]
  "employees" => array:257 [▶]
]
```

(I am using db for storing)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use `putMany()` wrong. I bet it'd be sufficient for you need to just use regular `put()`:

```
Cache::put('employees', $employees, 1440);
```

but if you want `putMany()` then you need to prepare source array first, which you are not doing:

```
$data = [
    'fields' => whateverItComesFrom(),
    'employees' => API::callAPI('GET', $data, $params),
];
Cache::putMany($data, 1440);
```

**EDIT**

As other users mentioned in comments, aside from incorrect usage, the DB storage may also contribute to the issue as, depending on size of the data you want to cache, it may simply exceed database type limits, i.e. 
`BLOB` is just 65535 bytes (64KB) (which suffices for most cases, but you have 200+ entries in array...). `MEDIUMBLOB` is 16777215 bytes (16 MB) and `LONGBLOB` for 4294967295 bytes (4 GB), so it may be worth checking that aspect too and change column type if needed.

Comment: I tried this, and I am still getting null (and nothing is stored into db).

Comment: ensure that you get any data from your `callAPI()`

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski `"employees" => array:257 [▶]` should communicate that information is coming back from their API. Might be a cache configuration issue?

Comment: @TimLewis - I set **CACHE_DRIVER=database**. I just tried file as a storage, and this is working. Maybe the array is too big for the text field?

Comment: @Sasha change text field to `BLOB` or `LONGBLOB`, but I recommend to use `redis` if You want centralize cache storage in case of multi-server (-instance) system

Comment: @num8er - the text limit caused the issue.

Comment: @Sasha change field type `ALTER TABLE cacheTable MODIFY fieldName LONGBLOB`

Answer (score 4):

I have found the issue - the limit of the text field was the reason why cache didn't work. Change the type to LONGBLOB (thanks num8er for advice), and now it is working.